# как сделать json словарь с таким видом? (сохранение в файл test.json)

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

такой json словарь должен получиться
(в файле test.json)

```json
{
'test':[
    [5, 6, 7], 
    [1,2,3,4]
],
'test2':[
    [2, 37, 213], 
    [1,2,3,323]
],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = dict([('test', [
    [5, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
]), ('test2', [
    [2, 37, 213],
    [1, 2, 3, 323]
])])

>>> {'test': [[5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 'test2': [[2, 37, 213], [1, 2, 3, 323]]}

print(json.dumps(json.loads(json.dumps(d)), indent=4, sort_keys=True))

{
    "test": [
        [
            5,
            6,
            7
        ],
        [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        ]
    ],
    "test2": [
        [
            2,
            37,
            213
        ],
        [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            323
        ]
    ]
}
```